# Is it possible to get oauth working in services-7.x-3.x?

Tags: 7, services, authentication-authorization

Any quick pointers on getting oauth working in Drupal 7?

My need is to implement 2-legged oAuth in order to authenticate consumers to a service endpoint with (the equivalent of) an API key.

At http://drupal.org/node/1336974#comment-5305810 marcingy says he committed the patch in #18. There have been releases of 7.x-3.x-dev since that comment and I don't see that patch in the latest releases...but maybe it's been reworked. What's really strange to me is that the 7.x-3.x-dev version of services (services/auth/services_oauth/services_oauth.info) still depends on the defunct oauth_common.module. I figure that would have been removed since there was never a D7 release of oauth_common...?

The patch in #18 (http://drupal.org/node/1336974#comment-5283802) also doesn't seem to remove the oauth_common dependency. (I guess that patch was for D6.)

I'm gathering that the way to do oAuth on Drupal 7 is by using other modules aside from Services.

Thanks!

Comment: Just came across this issue, and sevices 7.x-3.x-dev from 2012-Mar-15 does include patch from [#15](http://drupal.org/node/1336974#comment-5260612).

Comment: Keep in mind that oauth_common is the name of the module inside the OAuth 7.x-3.x package, the dependency is not referring to the defunct project.